# Can I backup using Time Machine and restore to another account?

Tags: itunes, time-machine, backup, restore

I am planning to re-install the OSX when Mavericks release. I am also actually planning to change my username after re-installation.

I need to backup my whole personal folder under username "a", but if I changed my username to "b", Can I still be restoring my personal data to "b"?

I know generally there is no problem for this, but I am wondering if iTunes library still recognise my new username and locate my every music file location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly restore to another account from Time Machine, but you can rename the user *after* the restore. After the fresh installation of OS X, restore the data and then do the user rename.

Follow the process outlined in [Changing user account short name](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3872) to rename your user "a" to user "b".

Comment: Thanks, but will my iTunes recognise the library's songs and Podcasts after renaming my account? It is most important thing that I concern.

Comment: Yes, it will. iTunes does not really depend on your OS X login username. As long as your iTunes store account is the same, things should be fine with all your media.
Note that I mentioned renaming the user *after* the data restore.