# Get selective folders of Time Machine backup on a new iMac

Tags: time-machine, backup

I have a Time Machine backup of my former computer, but it's filled with stuff I don't want (someone said steamapps ghost folders?) and so I've installed on the new one a new version of Mavericks and I want to just pick the iTunes music folder (and some others) and copy it on the new system.

Question is how can I drag (or script-get or whatever-get) the whole folder which is divided between all the backups and drop it where I want it?

I don't want to use Migration Assistant, because you have to restore the whole account.

Comment: This might help as well http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100882/can-i-backup-using-time-machine-and-restore-to-another-account?rq=1

Comment: this won't solve my problem. the iTunes music folder in the backup it's in /library/application support because it was shared among the users. I don't want to restore any of my previous user because I think there are bugged programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open finder and navigate to the folder on the Time Machine volume and drag it on to your desktop.

Time Machine places each backup in it's own folder so you can easily get to the one folder you want to restore and do it by hand. You can use the Time Machine interface to restore that folder as well, but Finder is more direct. You are correct so skip migration assistant as it's not the right tool for your job.

Comment: but what about multiple versions? do I have to drag all of them and merge manually?

Comment: @fra9001 If you take the most current backup it will automagically create a copy based on the most recent version. If you want another version, take that one at whatever point in time makes sense to you.